# C# open variable file with error message

Tags: c#, console-application

I can't figure out how to have the console error check the user input then open the file that is requested. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my current program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">Enter File to open.");//Prompt user for file name

            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(Console.ReadLine())) 
                throw new FileNotFoundException();//Check for errors

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You stuffed up!"); //Display error message
            }
        }
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@Console.ReadLine()); //set valid reply response
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: you have an infinite loop while(true) {} This will never end,whatever input you give. The code System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@Console.ReadLine()); is unreachable. You can break the loop if the file is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon in this line
`if (!File.Exists(Console.ReadLine())) ;`

You don't put semicolons on `if` statements, if you only have a single line after your `if` statement the following is fine

```
if (!File.Exists(Console.ReadLine()))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();//Check for errors
```

else

```
if (!File.Exists(Console.ReadLine())){
                throw new FileNotFoundException();//Check for errors

//some more code
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">Enter File to open.");//Prompt user for file name
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(s))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();//Check for errors
                else
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(s); //set valid reply response

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You stuffed up!"); //Display error message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just fixed it up yet it still won't open the file I enter into the console. Any ideas?

Comment: @JordanSlack See edit. Basically this line is unreachable `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@Console.ReadLine());`, move it inside your `try` block.

Comment: Thank you heaps for that, I've been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace ABCD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">Enter File to open.");//Prompt user for file name
                string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                        throw new FileNotFoundException();//Check for errors
                    else
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName); //set valid reply response

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You stuffed up!"); //Display error message
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

just make sure that you make an input of filename i.e. executable file with **".exe"** extension, and make sure that you provide full path.

i.e. make an input like "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", to open Internet Explorer